# how to empty() live ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have

```
$("#sendbid").live("click", function() {

   //here will be the ajax
   //after success:
   $("#personaltab").empty();
})
```

the personaltab is in the original code. the content is created on ajax and then when the user continue i want to check with live and empty the div

not working - i have tried it all!!!

Comment: can you please clarify your question

Comment: Is your handler actually being executed? Insert a `console.debug('here');` or `alert('here');` or something similar before/after the call to `empty()`.

Comment: *not working* is not an error description. Please clarify.

Comment: CLARIFY: when i say not working i mean that it does get to the point the empty() shoud be executed... i had alert before and after and it is ok... i get the alerts.
the empty is not working in IE - but does work in FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
i had  inside a  and for some reason the div that need to get the ajax by his id was duplicated

don't ask :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is a *jQuery* or *$* missing here :

```
jQuery("#sendbid").live("click", function() {
    jQuery("#personaltab").empty();
})
```

---

```
$("#sendbid").live("click", function() {
    $("#personaltab").empty();
})
```